# Why is chrome://settings and chrome://plugins broken?

Tags: google-chrome

**This is weird, way weird. When I go `Wrench` -> `Options` (`chrome://settings` in address bar):**

[image]

Similarly, when I try to use <kbd>F12</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>):

[image]

`chrome://plugins` is giving me a blank page:

[image]

==
If anyone is wondering, `view source` is working fine though.

Comment: … which version? Have you tried uninstalling/reinstalling? Clearing your profile?

Comment: @slhck mine is v14.0.835.163. btw what do you mean by clearing the profile? Do you mean the data kept in `C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data` ?

Comment: I'd first try reinstalling. Have you done that? And yes, the profile would be the folder you mentioned. Follow the guide here: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059

Comment: @slhck this is weird, initially I didn't want to do a reinstall/user data cleanup first. I've restarted it a couple of times but to no avail. Then after a while I decided to ignore it for the time-being and afterwards it crashed again. Then after recovering from crash it's fine o.o, weird chrome fat bug.